# Azure App Service autoscale incorrect average CPU evaluation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We are investigating problem with Azure App Service autoscale. Sometimes instances are removed when CPU usage is above set threshold.

Autoscale is setup according to following guidelines:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-best-practices

Rules are:

- Avg. CPU >=70% during last 5 minutes add one instance
- (Avg. CPU <=50%
  AND Max CPU <= 60%) during last 5 minutes remove one instance

Cool down period = 10 minutes for all rules

We determined that issue is caused by autoscale observing wrong values of average CPU utilization for App Service Plan:
[image: Difference between actual CPU usage and CPU usage observed by autoscale]

As you can see difference is sometimes dramatic (55% vs 24%).

We have enabled diagnostic logging for autoscale evaluations to storage account. And found following logs:

```
{ "time": "2019-11-18T07:27:02.1437280Z", "resourceId": "---removed---", "category": "AutoscaleEvaluations", "operationName": "MetricEvaluation", "correlationId": "b8265c6f-47b8-4cd4-9c59-c710b407d043", "properties": {"targetResourceId":"---removed---","metricName":"CpuPercentage","metricNamespace":"","timeGrain":"00:01:00","timeGrainStatistic":"Average","startTime":"11/18/2019 7:21:00 AM","endTime":"11/18/2019 7:26:00 AM","data":"[47.666666666666664,45.428571428571431,48.666666666666664,44.0,0.0,0.0]"}}


{ "time": "2019-11-18T07:27:02.1437280Z", "resourceId": "---removed---", "category": "AutoscaleEvaluations", "operationName": "ScaleRuleEvaluation", "correlationId": "b8265c6f-47b8-4cd4-9c59-c710b407d043", "properties": {"targetResourceId":"---removed---","metricName":"CpuPercentage","metricNamespace":"microsoft.web/serverfarms","timeGrain":"00:01:00","timeGrainStatistic":"Average","timeWindow":"00:05:00","timeAggregationType":"Average","operator":"GreaterThanOrEqual","threshold":"70","observedValue":"30.9603174603175","estimateScaleResult":"NotTriggered"}}
```

Notice that last two values in data collection of first log is 0.0 and observerValue in second log is 30.9603174603175. We have verified that CPU usage during that time frame never wen below 40 percent.

It seems that autoscale logic just uses 0.0 instead of missing values (null) and this is wrong for average calculation.

Is this behavior expected? For now we have set autoscale time window to 10 minutes for scale out and 15 minutes for scale in to minimize an error. Is there a better workaround?

## UPDATE:

Full autoscale profile json: https://gist.github.com/samfromlv/b706cfd598816e273c096ef05350e939

Comment: Nice observation! Did you select multiple values for 'Instance' dimension of 'CPU Percentage' metric ? If yes, autoscale will aggregate the 'CPU Percentage' metric across the selected values, not evaluate the metric for each values individually. I Suggest you to double check if this is the reason for the difference. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have verified that all rules in autoscale profile use default settings for dimension filter, default setting is 'All values' for 'Instance' dimension. I will add full autoscale profile json to the question.